# Import Error then I try to import tfds. Using Tensorflow-Macos

Tags: python, tensorflow, importerror, tensorflow-datasets

I want to test out Tensorflow on my Macbook Air (2020), but when I try to import Tensorflow-Datasets I get some Errors. I used miniconda to create an environment and to use Tensorflow for macOS.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[2], line 3
      1 import tensorflow as tf
      2 # Brining in tensorflow datasets for fashion mnist 
----> 3 import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
      4 # Bringing in matplotlib for viz stuff
      5 from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

File ~/miniconda/envs/env-tf2/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow_datasets/__init__.py:43
     41 _TIMESTAMP_IMPORT_STARTS = time.time()
     42 from absl import logging
---> 43 import tensorflow_datasets.core.logging as _tfds_logging
     44 from tensorflow_datasets.core.logging import call_metadata as _call_metadata
     46 _metadata = _call_metadata.CallMetadata()

File ~/miniconda/envs/env-tf2/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow_datasets/core/__init__.py:22
     18 # Allow to use `tfds.core.Path` in dataset implementation which seems more
     19 # natural than having to import a third party module.
     20 from etils.epath import Path
---> 22 from tensorflow_datasets.core import community
     23 from tensorflow_datasets.core.dataset_builder import BeamBasedBuilder
     24 from tensorflow_datasets.core.dataset_builder import BuilderConfig

File ~/miniconda/envs/env-tf2/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow_datasets/core/community/__init__.py:18
      1 # coding=utf-8
      2 # Copyright 2023 The TensorFlow Datasets Authors.
      3 #
   (...)
     13 # See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
     14 # limitations under the License.
     16 """Community dataset API."""
---> 18 from tensorflow_datasets.core.community.huggingface_wrapper import mock_builtin_to_use_gfile
     19 from tensorflow_datasets.core.community.huggingface_wrapper import mock_huggingface_import
     20 from tensorflow_datasets.core.community.load import builder_cls_from_module

File ~/miniconda/envs/env-tf2/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow_datasets/core/community/huggingface_wrapper.py:31
     28 from unittest import mock
     30 from etils import epath
---> 31 from tensorflow_datasets.core import dataset_builder
     32 from tensorflow_datasets.core import dataset_info
     33 from tensorflow_datasets.core import download

File ~/miniconda/envs/env-tf2/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow_datasets/core/dataset_builder.py:34
     32 from etils import epath
     33 from tensorflow_datasets.core import constants
---> 34 from tensorflow_datasets.core import dataset_info
     35 from tensorflow_datasets.core import dataset_metadata
     36 from tensorflow_datasets.core import decode

File ~/miniconda/envs/env-tf2/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow_datasets/core/dataset_info.py:47
     45 from etils import epath
     46 from tensorflow_datasets.core import constants
---> 47 from tensorflow_datasets.core import file_adapters
     48 from tensorflow_datasets.core import lazy_imports_lib
     49 from tensorflow_datasets.core import naming

File ~/miniconda/envs/env-tf2/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow_datasets/core/file_adapters.py:29
     26 from tensorflow_datasets.core.utils import type_utils
     27 from tensorflow_datasets.core.utils.lazy_imports_utils import tensorflow as tf
---> 29 from array_record.python import array_record_module
     31 ExamplePositions = List[Any]
     34 class FileFormat(enum.Enum):

ImportError: dlopen(/Users/lars/miniconda/envs/env-tf2/lib/python3.10/site-packages/array_record/python/array_record_module.so, 0x0002): tried: '/Users/lars/miniconda/envs/env-tf2/lib/python3.10/site-packages/array_record/python/array_record_module.so' (not a mach-o file), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/Users/lars/miniconda/envs/env-tf2/lib/python3.10/site-packages/array_record/python/array_record_module.so' (no such file), '/Users/lars/miniconda/envs/env-tf2/lib/python3.10/site-packages/array_record/python/array_record_module.so' (not a mach-o file)
```

I use Python 3.10.9 and following versions:

Tensorflow-Macos: 2.9.1
Tensorflow-Metal: 0.5.1
Tensorflow-Datasets: 4.9.0

Comment: what pip commands did you use to install tensoflow and tfds?

Comment: 'python -m pip install tensorflow-macos==2.9.1 tensorflow-metal==0.5.1 tensorflow-datasets'